# OpenGL ES Application Template Project Crashes in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, crash, ios-simulator, opengl-es-2.0

I am new to OpenGL ES 2.0.

I create a new project from XCode "OpenGLES Application Template", and try to run it, but it crashes in the iOS Simulator. When I debug it, I can see it draws the first cube successfully but then it goes somewhere which I can't see, and application crashes. I can not see any error reported in the console.

Some info:
My Xcode version is 3.2.6,
iOS Simulator is 4.3,
Running on Mac OSx 10.6.8,
iOS 4.3 SDK.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

I solved it, the problem did not have anything to do with OpenGLES2.0 as I originally thought.

Apparently my iOS Simulator 4.3 has some issues, because when I run it on iOS Simulator 4.1 it works flawlessly.

Thanks.

P.S. I don't know, if I should remove this question and answer or leave it here, because "title" of question is misleading, and has emphasis on OpenGLES when as it turned out, problem did not have anything to do with it.